# Python Using While loop avoid duplicate print

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using `Python Selenium` to parse some `live data` (Bets) , I am use `While loop`
this is some logic from my code

```
def parse():
    while True:
        x = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="bets-history"]/li[0]').text
        print(x)
```

**This code working but output is**

```
1.54x
1.54x
1.54x
1.54x
1.54x
1.54x
1.54x
1.54x
1.54x
1.54x
1.54x
1.54x
1.54x
1.54x
1.54x
1.54x
1.54x
1.54x
1.54x
13.5x
13.5x
13.5x
13.5x
13.5x
13.5x
13.5x
13.5x
13.5x
13.5x
13.5x
13.5x
```

What is best way to get only one print? for example like this

```
1.54x
13.5x
```

Comment: What happens if you have another set of `1.54` after those `13.5`? Would be printed again (once), or not because `1.54` was already printed, ever?

Answer (score 2):

You can assign a second variable (`y`) to the original variable (`x`) and then assign a new value to `x`. Then, in an if statement check if they aren't equal (`!=`).

**The code:**

```
def parse():
    x = ''
    while True:
        y = x
        x = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="bets-history"]/li[0]').text
        if y != x:
            print(x)
```

Comment: Of course, this wouldn't work if the duplicate values aren't consecutive, right?

Answer (score 1):

```
data = ['1.54x','1.54x','1.54x','1.54x','1.54x','1.54x','1.54x','1.54x','13.5x','13.5x','13.5x','13.5x','13.5x','13.5x','13.5x','13.5x']

previous_value = ''
for value in data:
    if value != previous_value:
        print(value)
        previous_value = value
```

Answer (score 1):

As you only want every value to be printed once, you can define a list, `xs`.

For each `x` defined, if the value of the `x` is already in the `xs` list, don't print or append the value of `x` to `xs`; else, print the value of `x` and append the value of `x` to `xs`:

```
def parse():
    xs = []
    while True:
        x = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="bets-history"]/li[0]').text
        if x not in xs:
            xs.append(x)
            print(x)
```

Comment: the OP obviously only meant consecutive values in his question so this isn't correct

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the uniquely received values. Later you can check if the newly received value already exists then do not print this value otherwise print it to console.

```
def parse():
    stored_data = []
    while True:
        x = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="bets-history"]/li[0]').text
        if x not in stored_data:
            print(x)
            stored_data.append(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `set` for faster lookups instead of `list`.

Since in your question there are only two values, it won't be much of a difference looking up in `list` and a `set`. But if there are `n` values,

> `list` will take **O(n)** time to lookup

> `set` will take just **O(1)** time to lookup

```
def parse():
    s = set()
    while True:
        x = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="bets-history"]/li[0]').text
        if x not in s:
           s.add(x)
           print(x)
```